# Passar expressão lambda para outra classe executar C#

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Tem como passar uma expressão lambda para uma classe, e depois executa-la ?
Algo como código abaixo.

Esta dando erro no select new da expressão

> Erro: Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) C:\Users\Nicola Bogar\Desktop\Software\Bogars.Corporativo.Solution\Bogars.Corporativo.Aplicacao\Class1.cs   22  26  Bogars.Corporativo.Aplicacao

```
public class ClasseFilha : ClasseBse
{
    public ClasseFilha()
    {
        DataContext context = new DataContext();

        expression = from cidade in context.Cidade.AsNoTracking()
                     join estado in context.Estado.AsNoTracking() on cidade.EstadoHandle equals estado.Handle
                     join pais in context.Pais.AsNoTracking() on estado.PaisHandle equals pais.Handle
                     where cidade.Handle == 1
                     select new
                     {
                         Handle = cidade.Handle,
                         Nome = cidade.Nome,
                         Sigla = cidade.Sigla,
                         PaisHandle = pais.Handle,
                         PaisNome = pais.Nome,
                         EstadoHandle = estado.Handle,
                         EstadoNome = estado.Nome
                     };
    }                
}

public class ClasseBse
{
    public LambdaExpression expression;

    public void ExecuteLambadaExpression()
    {
        expression.Compile();
    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi o que pretende fazer, poderia melhorar sua pergunta?

Comment: Eu gostaria de montar uma expressão Lambda, passar para uma propriedade LambdaExpression, e quando eu quiser utilizar eu compilo essa expressão Lambda que está criada nesta propriedade.